# Spring Integration: DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available is thrown from advice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Boot along with Spring integration version `4.2.5.RELEASE`.
I'm trying to setup a retry advice correctly for one of my Spring Integration flows that invokes a remote http service.
The simplified draft of the flow looks like this: 
`1. Gateway --> 2. flow that sets required http headers --> 3. common outbound gateway template --> 4. http-outbound-gateway.`

**What I want to achieve:** 
If the http operation is hanging or the remote service is not available, try to send the request again at most 5 times and then put the Message into a recovery channel where I can perform some additional actions, but also I would like to return a valid response to the gateway that is the entry point of my flow (`FetchNewIdsResponseDTO`).

**Relevant code for the individual flow elements:**

**1. Gateway:**

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = GATEWAY_ERROR_CHANNEL_NAME,
            defaultReplyTimeout = "2000")
    public interface FetchNewIdsGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = GATEWAY_INPUT_CHANNEL_NAME)
        FetchNewIdsResponseDTO fetch(Object o);
    }
```

**2. flow that sets required http headers:**

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow fetchNewIdsOutboundGatewayFlow(@Value("${worker-app.hostname}") String workerAppHostname,
                                                   CommonOutboundGatewayTemplate.CommonOutboundGateway gateway) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationFlowConstants.OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_TEMPLATE_INPUT_CHANNEL)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h
                        .header(CommonMessageHeaders.WORKER_APP_REQUEST_HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethod.GET.toString())
                        .header(CommonMessageHeaders.WORKER_APP_LOCATION, workerAppHostname)
                        .header(CommonMessageHeaders.WORKER_APP_REQUEST_PATH, ServiceIntegrationControllerEndpoints.FETCH_NEW_IDS)
                        .header(CommonMessageHeaders.FLOW_NAME, IntegrationFlowTypes.FETCH_NEW_IDS.getFlowName()))
                .handle(Object.class, gateway::send)
                .get();
    }
```

**3. common outbound gateway template:**

```
    @MessagingGateway(name = COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_NAME,
            defaultReplyChannel = GATEWAY_OUTPUT_CHANNEL,
            errorChannel = GATEWAY_ERROR_CHANNEL,
            defaultReplyTimeout = "2000")
    public interface CommonOutboundGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_INPUT_CHANNEL)
        Object send(Object o, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers);
    }
```

**4. http-outbound-gateway:**

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow commonOutboundGatewayFlow(@Qualifier(REST_TEMPLATE_NAME) RestTemplate restTemplate,
                                              @Qualifier(COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_RECOVERY_CHANNEL) MessageChannel recoveryChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_INPUT_CHANNEL)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(CommonMessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, CommonMessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON_VALUE))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("{url}{path}", restTemplate)
                        .httpMethodFunction(m -> m.getHeaders().get(CommonMessageHeaders.WORKER_APP_REQUEST_HTTP_METHOD))
                        .charset("UTF-8")
                        .encodeUri(false)
                        .mappedRequestHeaders(CommonMessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
                        .mappedResponseHeaders(CommonMessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                        .uriVariable("url", m -> m.getHeaders().get(CommonMessageHeaders.WORKER_APP_LOCATION))
                        .uriVariable("path", m -> m.getHeaders().get(CommonMessageHeaders.WORKER_APP_REQUEST_PATH))
                        , e -> e.advice(retryAdvice(recoveryChannel)))   
                .channel(COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_OUTPUT_TRANSFORMER_CHANNEL)
                .get();
    }
```

**Retry advice:**

```
     @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice(@Qualifier(COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_RECOVERY_CHANNEL) MessageChannel recoveryChannel) {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        advice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(recoveryChannel));
        advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());

        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);

        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
        backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(5.0);
        backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(1000L);

        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }
```

**And finally, the flow that could perform additional advice actions and transforming the Message (error handling)**

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fetchNewIdsErrorRecovery() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(CommonOutboundGatewayTemplate.COMMON_OUTBOUND_GATEWAY_RECOVERY_CHANNEL)
// -->ADDITIONAL RECOVERY ACTIONS WOULD GO HERE, BEFORE TRANSFORMATION!
                .<MessagingException, Message>transform(p -> {
                    Object failedPayload = p.getFailedMessage().getPayload();
                    return MessageBuilder.createMessage(failedPayload, p.getFailedMessage().getHeaders());
        })
```

**What I can see from the logs**

```
    2017-01-11 21:56:32,318 2505 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=0
2017-01-11 21:56:32,831 3018 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=1
2017-01-11 21:56:32,831 3018 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=1
2017-01-11 21:56:33,833 4020 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=2
2017-01-11 21:56:33,833 4020 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=2
2017-01-11 21:56:34,835 5022 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=3
2017-01-11 21:56:34,835 5022 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=3
2017-01-11 21:56:35,836 6023 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=4
2017-01-11 21:56:35,836 6023 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=4
2017-01-11 21:56:35,838 6025 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=5
2017-01-11 21:56:35,838 6025 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry failed last attempt: count=5
2017-01-11 21:56:50,900 21087 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds, headers={history=common-outbound-gateway-recovery-channel,fetch-new-ids-error-log-channel,trace-log-channel, id=f27f1633-9e5f-a3eb-f1b7-6bc04cecf167, timestamp=1484168210900}]
2017-01-11 21:56:50,902 21089 [main] ERROR FetchNewIdsFlowLoggers$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ccbdfda2 - [STEP 1::fetch new IDs] Error while executing the flow, DETAILS: HEADERS: {history=common-outbound-gateway-recovery-channel,fetch-new-ids-error-log-channel,com.szyszy.superscraper.integration.flows.fetchnewids.FetchNewIdsFlowLoggers.fetchNewIdsErrorLogHandler.serviceActivator.handler,fetchNewIdsErrorLogHandler, id=fe6fed47-bcca-ac61-3f09-6f573e2b0cde, timestamp=1484168210901}PAYLOAD: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds
2017-01-11 21:56:50,903 21090 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds, headers={history=common-outbound-gateway-recovery-channel,trace-log-channel, id=651ded47-22c4-d2a6-7326-c08960ff9247, timestamp=1484168210903}]
2017-01-11 21:56:52,484 22671 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, history=common-outbound-gateway-error-transformer-channel,common-outbound-gateway-error-log-channel,trace-log-channel, id=da0fff16-9fef-69e9-ed9d-bfcde7e01e29, timestamp=1484168212484}]
2017-01-11 21:56:52,486 22673 [main] ERROR CommonOutboundGatewayTemplateLoggers$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fe9ed5c - [OUTBOUND GATEWAY OPERATION] Failed to send message to the worker application, DETAILS: HEADERS: {replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, history=common-outbound-gateway-error-transformer-channel,common-outbound-gateway-error-log-channel,com.szyszy.superscraper.integration.commonflows.outbound.CommonOutboundGatewayTemplateLoggers.commonOutboundGatewayErrorLogHandler.serviceActivator.handler,commonOutboundGatewayErrorLogHandler, id=08ca5452-68d4-4464-6fa7-961632330405, timestamp=1484168212485}PAYLOAD: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available -- Failed payload: : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds
2017-01-11 21:56:52,489 22676 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, history=common-outbound-gateway-error-transformer-channel,trace-log-channel, id=590c49a7-3d4b-ced2-b2bc-3250508e1986, timestamp=1484168212489}]
2017-01-11 21:56:52,490 22677 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4993febc, history=common-outbound-gateway-error-transformer-channel,com.szyszy.superscraper.integration.commonflows.outbound.CommonOutboundGatewayTemplate.gatewayErrorChannel.bridgeTo.handler,common-outbound-gateway-error-response-transformer-channel,trace-log-channel, id=e12b2aa5-b471-bed0-c627-7620cb9c8bcf, timestamp=1484168212490}]
```

Especially this is interesting: 
`payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available`

### **CONCLUSIONS and QUESTION**

Since my error channel is reached, the response object is created correctly (`FetchNewIdsResponseDTO`) and goes back to the first gateway. After the Message reached the recovery channel, a `DestinationResolutionException` was thrown. Actually, I don't understand the reason why this is happening.
My `fetchNewIdsErrorRecovery` flow builds a new `Message`, copying the original headers, so the reply-channel should be available in my understanding.

How could I perform any additional actions (through the recovery channel) while get rid of this exception at the same time?
Could someone please enlighten me about the advice's `recoveryCallback` purpose?

Is it created for error handling or just differently, do some additional actions and rely on the http gateway's error handling in the end?

**UPDATE:**

Adding the `.bridge(null)` call before `.get()` solved the issue, this is log output after the issue is resolved:

```
        2017-01-16 22:11:42,376 2260 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=0
    2017-01-16 22:11:42,890 2774 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=1
    2017-01-16 22:11:42,890 2774 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=1
    2017-01-16 22:11:43,891 3775 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=2
    2017-01-16 22:11:43,891 3775 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=2
    2017-01-16 22:11:44,891 4775 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=3
    2017-01-16 22:11:44,891 4775 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=3
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,893 5777 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=4
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,893 5777 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry: count=4
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,893 5777 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Checking for rethrow: count=5
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,894 5778 [main] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate - Retry failed last attempt: count=5
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,895 5779 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds, headers={history=common-outbound-gateway-recovery-channel,fetch-new-ids-error-log-channel,trace-log-channel, id=5872d71d-29fa-a71f-0c9f-800d4decc6cb, timestamp=1484601105895}]
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,897 5781 [main] ERROR FetchNewIdsFlowLoggers$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f05c6801 - [STEP 1::fetch new IDs] Error while executing the flow, DETAILS: HEADERS: {history=common-outbound-gateway-recovery-channel,fetch-new-ids-error-log-channel,com.szyszy.superscraper.integration.flows.fetchnewids.FetchNewIdsFlowLoggers.fetchNewIdsErrorLogHandler.serviceActivator.handler,fetchNewIdsErrorLogHandler, id=e176b462-d02e-0603-b6ec-9a79588794e8, timestamp=1484601105896}PAYLOAD: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,898 5782 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$ThrowableHolderException: java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://testWorkerAppHostname/newIds, headers={history=common-outbound-gateway-recovery-channel,trace-log-channel, id=7cc7379b-0320-661e-657c-d1d5a0c6a741, timestamp=1484601105898}]
    2017-01-16 22:11:45,900 5784 [main] INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload=FetchNewIdsResponseDTO{links=null, ids=null, RestResponseDTO{errorMessage='Error while fetching new ids - Remote server is not available!', success=false}}, headers={workerAppLocation=http://testWorkerAppHostname, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4d0402b, workerAppRequestPath=/newIds, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4d0402b, workerAppRequestHTTPMethod=GET, history=fetchNewIdsFlow$FetchNewIdsGateway,fetch-new-ids-gateway-in-channel,in-child-context-individual-outbound-gateway-template-channel,fetchNewIdsOutboundGatewayFlow.channel#0,commonOutboundToWorkerGateway,common-outbound-gateway-input-channel,commonOutboundGatewayFlow.channel#0,fetchNewIdsErrorResponseTransformer2.channel#0,trace-log-channel, id=ee760170-a73f-ddcf-8a1a-c0835f773374, flowName=FETCH_NEW_IDS, Content-Type=application/json, timestamp=1484601105900
```

Comment: Yeah... Nothing obvious. Would you mind to simplify the flow somehow? Or even better share some simple Spring Boot app to play from our side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I found what the problem.

You have to place `.bridge(null)` just after `.<MessagingException, Message>transform()`, before `get()`.

The problem with a `replyChannel` header that Framework consults a `requestMessage` for that purpose. not `reply` object.

Not sure that we are going to change something in the Framework on the matter, but that is a fact, that `reply` doesn't not make affect to the `output` resolution decision.

We can do that via Routing Slip pattern, buy you have to place a header on the matter in advance anyway.

The [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4207) ticket on the matter.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and the JIRA issue link.
I applied the changes you suggested, and now the flow works fine and I have the correct transformed object without the resolution issue :)
Please see the updated answer, I pasted the logs from the testcase, for reference.

Not sure if I understand everything crystal-clear.
What is the "reply object"? 
What produces this object / what's the difference between a normal `requestMessage` and the `reply` object?
Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: `requestMessage` what component receives. `reply` - what component produces.

Comment: Ahh sure, obviously. It was a dumb question, thank you! :)